# cURL repeating init for different urls

Tags: php, curl

Let say I got a list of 100 websites and I would like to grab < title >< / title > meta tag.
I found this script which is working fine, but I don't know how to repeat the whole process for new websites:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init ("http://www.mywebsite.com");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $page = curl_exec ($ch);
    echo $page;

    $file = 'title.txt';
    $regex = '/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/s';
    if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[1];
    else
    echo "Unable to find preg_match";
    file_put_contents($file, html_entity_decode($list[0]));
    ?>
```

What's the best way to repeat the whole curl_init for new websites?

For exampple:

1. Go to -> http://www.mywebsite.com
2. Search for title tag
3. Insert title to title.txt
4. Go to 2nd website from the list -> http://www.mywebsite2.com
5. Searcg for title tag
6. Insert title to title.txt
7. Go to 3rd website from the list -> http://www.mywebsite3.com
8. etc erc.

Also, what's the best way to handle files for further use from PHP point of view? Should I use FILE_APPEND or try to save each title in new file e.g. mywebsite.com_title.txt, mywebsite2.com_title.txt etc?
Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for my stupid questions, I'm 100% newbie to PHP :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand your question correctly, you want to run your code on multiple sites.  You could put the addresses in an array, and then loop over the array.  I took your code about and wrapped it in the following loop.

```
<?php
$sites = array("http://www.mywebsite.com",
               "http://www.mywebsite2.com",
               "http://www.mywebsite3.com"
              );


    foreach ($sites as $site) {
      #$ch = curl_init ("http://www.mywebsite.com");
      $ch = curl_init ($site);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $page = curl_exec ($ch);
      echo $page;

      $file = 'title.txt';
      $regex = '/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/s';
      if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
      echo $list[1];
      else
      echo "Unable to find preg_match";
      file_put_contents($file, html_entity_decode($list[0]));
    }
    ?>
```